# how to fix this error while using metasploit on parrot os kde

Tags: kde, parrotsec, metasploit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
        4: from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1348:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1348:in `require'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:50:in `<class:Specification>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands;

`apt install ruby zlib1g-dev libpq-dev libpcap0.8-dev libsqlite3-dev`

It should fix the issue. Can you check if you have already ruby installed on your OS?

Comment: thanks alot bro for the help